# How can I force python to use dumbdbm module to create a new database?

Tags: python, database, unix, shelve

The `shelve` module is implemented on top of the `anydbm` module. This module acts as a façade for 4 different specific DBM implementations, and it will pick the first module available when creating a new database, in the following order:

- **dbhash**
  (deprecated but still the first `anydbm` choice). This is a proxy for the `bsddb` module, `.open()` is really `bsddb.hashopen()`
- **gdbm**, Python module for the GNU DBM library, offering more functionality than the `dbm` module can offer when used with this same library.
- **dbm**, a proxy module using either the `ndbm`, BSD DB and GNU DBM libraries (chosen when Python is compiled).
- **dumbdbm**, a pure-python implementation.

But in my system although I have `dbhash` for some reason I want it to create the db just with the `dumbdbm`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to resemble a system. The base system creates a db file which uses dumbdbm and then uses that file as an input to another program. If I use any other db I have to change the other program to read the new file properly and we are trying to not change the code as far as we can.

Comment: Only dumbdbm is available on Windows. If you want to move 'shelve' files between Linux and Windows, they have to use the dumbdbm format.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot control what db module `shelve.open` uses, but there are workarounds.

The best is usually to create the db yourself and pass it to [the `Shelf` constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf) manually, instead of calling `shelve.open`:

```
db = dumbdbm.open('mydb')
shelf = shelve.Shelf(db)
```

The first parameter is any object that provides a `dict`-like interface that can store strings, which is exactly what any `*dbm` object is.